# Symlinking executable surrounded with dylib not working

Tags: macos, symbolic-link, osx-yosemite

The executable

```
$ /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel
```

works fine:

```
Mathematica 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2014 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:=
```

However if I symlink it under `math` in `/usr/local/bin` (or if I add `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/` to `PATH`), then I get the following error :

```
$ math
dlopen(/SystemFiles, 1): image not found
```

In its directory, `MathKernel` is surrounded with `dylib` files, so I believe it's the cause of the error. But then I thought adding a directory to `PATH` would avoid this kind of problem.

Running OSX Yosemite 10.10.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem creating a symbolic link to Mathematica.

Try to use an alias like this:

```
alias math="/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel"
```

Comment: Not sure why you've been downvoted. Very helpful. I've copied the line the in my `bash_profile` and it works great now. Thanks !