# Symlink executable not working on OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, symbolic-link

I am trying to create a symlink under `math` in `/usr/local/bin` for Mathematica (`/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel`). The executable works, and even if I go through Finder to the symlink and I click it it works. But when I call `math` from the command line I get

```
$ math
dlopen(/SystemFiles, 1): image not found
```

I am running OSX El Capitan 10.11.6.

This is an exact duplicate of [Symlinking executable surrounded with dylib not working](https://superuser.com/questions/896340/symlinking-executable-surrounded-with-dylib-not-working), but the answer given there (to create an alias) does not work for me. I absolutely need for another program (SageMath) to be able to call `math`, and this other program does not read my alias definitions.

Comment: Some programs are sensitive to the NAME of the program itself.  Basically, they use the same code, but behave different depending on the NAME itself.  What happens if you create the symlink as "WolfamKernel"?  I know that doesn't help you yet when another program is trying to call it as "math", but it's a start.  Also, what happens if you create a link called "math" in that MacOS folder, and call it from there?  If that works, trying adding that MacOS folder to your search PATH, and call "math" while "in" another directory.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I tried creating the symlink as WolframKernel and got the same thing (image not found).

Comment: What do you mean by "that" MacOS folder? The one in which the other program is?

Comment: By that MacOS folder, I meant /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS. I don't have a Mathematica, but I assumed WolframKernal was the executable, and MacOS is the folder.  Try creating a symlink called math in MacOS dir. That could tell you in Mathematica/Wolfram just doesn't like being called from another directory or doesn't like being called "math" (or both).

Comment: Either way, the solution might be the same: write a "wrapper" script called "math", somewhere in your normal PATH. The script will "cd" to /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS and then call WolframKernel there.  If you're trying to pass arguments like filenames, that will take just a little more work, as you'll need to adjust the paths to the files to account for the fact that you're not in the same dir as you started from.

Comment: When I put the symlink in the MacOS dir it does work. So it doesn't like being called from elsewhere...

Comment: One last question: Can "in my normal PATH" mean "in /usr/local/bin"? Can I put the script there?

Comment: Also if you would like to put the script as an answer to this question I am happy to give it the green check mark. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the answer from Comments to a real answer.

A couple of solutions seem like they would work:

1. In the /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/ folder,make a symlink like `ln -s WolframKernel math`, and then add that /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/ to the search PATH in your shell.
2. Or, write a small shell script called "math", and put it somewhere already on your PATH (like /usr/local/bin, although I prefer to have a "scripts" folder separate from binaries).  The shell script should be pretty simple, with basically 2 commands: `cd /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/` and then just `WolframKernel`.  You might need to pass arguments from the shell into the shell script, which isn't hard, but the syntax will depend on the shell used in the script (not the shell that it's called from).

From the comments, it sounds like #1 should work, and it's the simplest.  However, be aware that updates to Mathematica will probably remove that symlink, so #2 might be a more stable solution.